# Is it necessary to use express for node for moderate apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If i have a project with about 30 or 40 routes!?

Is it easy to handle cookies andthe auth without express !?

How % of devs using express compared to bare bones node (For performance and simplicity)

Comment: You question is a `primarily opinion-based` and could be close for this. But be more specific about why you don't want to use express? Why do you have this question ?

Comment: For performance and simplicity

Comment: For opinions seek reddit. SO is all about answering technical questions. Hope you find your answers.

Comment: This is entirely an opinion question and should probably be closed.  In general, I see zero reason to make your own web framework for node.js rather than use an existing web framework.  Creating your own framework is just extra work in the way of getting your app up and running and coded with the appropriate features.  Frameworks like Express or Koa are sufficiently "unopinionated" and don't get in the way of you coding your app.  Most developers will use a web framework with node.js because it saves you a ton of time.  Voting to close the question as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is a very good Nodejs framework and most used so it's the one selected by most project.

It already contain a lot's of documentation and package who are already configured to work well with express so it can help you to find more relative project or developer if you try to hire lot's of people.

But Express is not the only one ! And you can choose another one based on your needs, check out [Koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa), it's an express-lite